# How to install tutorial on ROS Melodic Morenia?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I followed the tutorial of [Understanding ROS Nodes](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes)

In the Prerequisites,I tried to install the tutorial with the command

```
sudo apt-get install ros-<melodic>-ros-tutorials
```

but I only got :

```
bash: melodic: No such file or directory
```

I tried to replace melodic with all the other command possible like indigo, jade, kinetic.Non of them work. I have tried apt-get update too but it didn't work either :(

The ubuntu version I used is 18.04 LTS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303419/how-to-install-tutorial-on-ros-melodic-morenia?/) by [cedric](https://answers.ros.org/users/37520/cedric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The directions for that step are:

> $ sudo apt-get install ros--ros-tutorials
>
> Replace '' with the name of your ROS distribution (e.g. indigo, jade, kinetic)

Note that `<distro>` includes the angle brackets, so the final command should be:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-ros-tutorials
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-09-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try this:

```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-ros-tutorials
```

---

Originally posted by [mitchallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/49960/mitchallen/) with karma: 11 on 2019-12-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1